# Keyboard not detected when installing

Tags: keyboard

Ubuntu do not detect the keyboard on an older MSI laptop.

I have tried severel times to even nuke the hard disk and reinstall ubuntu - with the same result: even during installation (when choosing the keyboard layout and setting up personal information) Ubuntu do not find the keyboard and I have to use the onscreen one.

After installation I can't find the way to dectect the keyboard. What to do?